# What is the difference between "load address" and "relocation address"?

Tags: gcc, linker, ld

Regarding the `AT (...)` directive for `ld`, [this source](http://www.math.utah.edu/docs/info/ld_3.html) states:

`AT ( ldadr )
The expression ldadr that follows the AT keyword specifies the load address of the section. The default (if you do not use the AT keyword) is to make the load address the same as the relocation address. This feature is designed to make it easy to build a ROM image.`

I've been searching but have not found a clear definition of what is meant by "load address" and "relocation address".

I understand that when object files are linked together, code is "relocated" in that jump addresses, etc. are rewritten to point to the correct offset within the combined machine code. So is the "relocation address" the offset within the resulting object code where a section begins? If so, how could the "load address" of a section possibly be something different?

How is the output of the linker affected if these 2 addresses are different?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Difference is crucial. Relocation address is addend to all relocs in section. So if it differ with load address, nothing will really work in this section -- all relocs inside section will be resolved to wrong values.

So why do we need technique like this? Not so much applications, but suppose ([from here](http://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/ld-2.9.1/html_node/ld_22.html)) you do have on your architecture extremely fast memory at 0x1000

Then you may take two sections to have relocation address 0x1000:

```
.text0 0x1000 : AT (0x4000) { o1/*.o(.text) }
__load_start_text0 = LOADADDR (.text0);
__load_stop_text0 = LOADADDR (.text0) + SIZEOF (.text0);
.text1 0x1000 : AT (0x4000 + SIZEOF (.text0)) { o2/*.o(.text) }
__load_start_text1 = LOADADDR (.text1);
__load_stop_text1 = LOADADDR (.text1) + SIZEOF (.text1);
. = 0x1000 + MAX (SIZEOF (.text0), SIZEOF (.text1));
```

Now at runtime go ahead and when you need text1, manage it by yourself to be copied on right address from its actual load address:

```
extern char __load_start_text1, __load_stop_text1;
memcpy ((char *) 0x1000, &__load_start_text1,
      &__load_stop_text1 - &__load_start_text1);
```

And then use it, **as it was loaded** here naturally. This technique is called overlays.

I think, example is pretty clear.

Comment: Konstantin, thanks for your example. I think understand: all jumps, calls, etc. in the linked code are calculated as if the code will be loaded at the "relocation address", but at runtime, it is actually loaded at the "load address"? So is the "load address" actually the offset within the object file where the code appears? Or do object files (ELF, etc) contain directives which tell the loader where to put the code in memory at runtime?

Comment: To clarify what I am asking, once the linker has decided the "load address" for a section, how does that affect the output binary file?

Comment: Yes, it is part of ELF format if you are targeting UNIX system http://www.skyfree.org/linux/references/ELF_Format.pdf

Comment: OK, I see now... for each segment in an ELF file, there is a "program header" with *both* its offset within the file **and** its load address. Looking at a `vmlinux` Linux kernel binary with `readelf`, I can see it has 3 segments, each with more than 10 sections. Does that mean the bootloader will read those ELF headers and load each segment at the specified "load address"?

Comment: Actually never tried it with os kernel. I suppose, kernel do not use standard loader, and boot loader might ignore something from ELF header or process something else. I think it is simpler to try and look where are they.

Answer (score 2):

I've found a better answer after some searching:

> Every ... output section has two addresses. The first is the VMA, or
>   virtual memory address. This is the address the section will have when
>   the output file is run. The second is the LMA, or load memory address.
>   This is the address at which the section will be loaded. In most cases
>   the two addresses will be the same. An example of when they might be
>   different is when a data section is loaded into ROM, and then copied
>   into RAM when the program starts up (this technique is often used to
>   initialize global variables in a ROM based system). In this case the
>   ROM address would be the LMA, and the RAM address would be the VMA.

*Quoted from: https://www.sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Basic-Script-Concepts.html#Basic-Script-Concepts*

This means that in a section declaration like:

```
section [address] [(type)] :
  [AT(lma)]
  [ALIGN(section_align) | ALIGN_WITH_INPUT]
  [SUBALIGN(subsection_align)]
  [constraint]
  {
    output-section-command
    output-section-command
    …
  } [>region] [AT>lma_region] [:phdr :phdr …] [=fillexp]
```

`[address]` [is the VMA](https://www.sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Output-Section-Address.html#Output-Section-Address) and `[AT(lma)]` [is the LMA](https://www.sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Output-Section-LMA.html#Output-Section-LMA).